# Multiple IFs with AND /OR conditions Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
if(
   (
   document.myForm.B1.value == "Art-B1" &&
   document.myForm.Op1.value == "Art" &&
   document.myForm.Op1G.value < "6"
   )
 ) || 
   (
   document.myForm.B1.value == "Art-B1" &&
   document.myForm.Op2.value == "Art" &&
   document.myForm.Op2G.value < "6"
   ) ||
   (
   document.myForm.B1.value == "Art-B1" &
   document.myForm.Op1.value != "Art"
   ) || 
   (
   document.myForm.B1.value == "Art-B1" && 
   document.myForm.Op2.value != "Art"
   )
){
```

I am coding an enrollment system and I am getting stuck on the multiple IF conditions in JavaScript.

The Condition are:

```
If Subject Choice (B1)  is = Art
```

AND

(
If student has taken Art in Option Block 1 and achieved a grade 6 or below

OR

```
If student has taken Art in Option Block 2 and achieved a grade 6 or below
```

OR

```
Art is not selected from Option block 1
```

OR

```
Art is not selected from Option block 2)
```

THEN

```
Output Error.
```

I am sure it is the parenthesis, I have tried various different combinations but to no luck

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `document.myForm.Op1G.value < "6"))` <- remove last parenthesis. Also the < comparison is wrong because you compare strings.

Comment: `== "Art-B1" &` misses `&`

Comment: As a heads up, comparing form values such that `stringValue < "6"` may seem to work at first, but it actually doesn't. It performs string comparison, so for example `"15" < "6" === true`. If you want to compare as numbers you'll have to convert the values to numbers first.

Comment: Order of precendence. A && B || C is same as (A && B) || C... A || B && C would require parentheses if you mean A && C || A && C ie (A || B) && C vs A || (B && C) - later would be default and not required.. Just aids clarity..